# How to get resource value in javascript file in mvc 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the string from Resource file (resx) in `common.js` file(one common javascript file) but m not getting resource value.

Here is my code in which, I am trying to get resource value.(this code is written in `common.js` file)

```
function LoadStates() {
alert(resources_en);
$("#drpState").empty();
$("#drpCity").empty();
$("#drpState").append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("**please select a city**"));
$("#drpCity").append($('<option></option>').val("0").html(resources_en.city));
if ($("#drpRegCountry option:selected").val() != "" && $("#drpRegCountryoption:selected").val() != undefined) {
    var CountryID = $("#drpRegCountry option:selected").val().split(",");
    $("#SelectedCountryCode,#hdnCountryCode").val("+" + CountryID[1]);
    $("#hdnCountryCode").val(CountryID[1]);

    $("hdnCountryId").val(CountryID[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // url: "../Account/GetStates",
        url: "../Account/GetStates", // we are calling json method
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { countryid: CountryID[0] },
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                $("#drpState").append('<option value="' + v.Value + '">' +
                     v.Text + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".pageLoading").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $(".pageLoading").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

In "please select a city" I want value from my resource file.

Comment: If you're using MVC then you can create your custom tag helper to get resource value and use it to jvascript.

Comment: Thanks, i solved this one by using layout page.